# How to run Electron app on a server, and connect to it through a web browser from a client?

Tags: electron, remote-server

I’m interested in taking a Electron project, running it on a server, and connecting to the UI through a browser on my client.

Are there any existing projects that help with building something like this? Or is this functionality in some way built into the Electron framework?

Comment: this is not possible, as electron does not provides way to remote its ui into browser.

Comment: if `ui` means non-native part but only for HTML contents, that may able, but then that's normal web page.

Comment: Not possible to my knowledge, but you could in theory use Express or another Node.js web server, running within Electron on the server, to deliver content to a web browser remotely. Don't know how well it would scale!

Comment: Electron is the chrome renderer. Other than that it is just a window and a web-app that is rendered by the chrome renderer.

Comment: This would be awesome for something like Logseq that stores data on the filesystem so you could access it from any machine.  Authn/Authz would be a little tricky but setting up basic auth or even mTLS should be pretty easy if you or a small team are the only users.  If you needed to scale, there are better ways anyway.